# 5V Battery bank solution?

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator

I live in an area that gets hit by storms once or twice a year and the power would go out for a day or two each time. It doesn't justify buying a generator, but it's a nuisance not to be able to charge phones and tablets. So I thought it'd be fun to build a 5V battery bank for this purpose. My requirements are:

1. I want to leave it plugged to the wall outlet all the time so it'll be charged when the power goes out.
2. It doesn't have to be lightweight.
3. It doesn't "leak" when not being used.

My questions are:

1. What's the ideal battery for this application? I heard Li-ion batteries can be finicky and since I don't need the mobility, would lead-acid batteries be a good choice?
2. If I use 3 cells of lead-acid batteries, it'd be ~6.4v. Is it OK to feed that to the cell phone, or is it better to run it through a regulator?
3. If I run it through the regulator, would it draw some current even if it doesn't have a load. I.e. is it going to have a leak?

Thanks!

Comment: All rechargeable batteries have leaks. Your better off with some primary based chargers that take regular AA batteries. 10 year shelf life and all.

Comment: 12V AGC type lead battery. Keep it topped off with an off-the-shelf trickle charger. Use proper fuses. Stick in a buck converter that can accept up to 15V input and supplies 5.5V output. Put a bunch of USB ports on it, short the D+ and D- pin of each port. Happy charging.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only expect it to be needed once or twice a year, I'd go with lead-acids, set up for topping/float charging. Note that you'll want to set the charge voltages fairly precisely.

As to whether the phone battery can be charged directly from your backup battery, that is entirely a matter of the phone charger. Maybe yes, maybe no.

Comment: To the OP, do not connect anything over 5.5V to a USB powered device. The IC vendors have gotten in the habit of cutting things VERY close. There is almost no voltage margin between operating voltage and absolute maximum voltage on the input of a lot of these devices. A lot of USB connected IC's have an absolute max of 6V.